# How to prevent bounce in cocos2dx v3.7?

Tags: c++, c++11, cocos2d-x-3.0

Game scence:

```
....
   auto edgeBody = PhysicsBody::createEdgeBox(winSize,PHYSICSBODY_MATERIAL_DEFAULT,3);
    auto edgeNode = Node::create();
    edgeNode->setPosition(winSize.width/2+origin.x , winSize.height/2+origin.y+10);
    edgeNode->setPhysicsBody(edgeBody);
....
```

Ball:

```
auto dinosaurBody = PhysicsBody::createCircle(dinosaurSprite->getContentSize().width/2);
dinosaurSprite->setPhysicsBody(dinosaurBody);
```

When ball collide with edge body  it has  bounce , how i remove it?

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dinosaurBody->setRestitution(0)
```

also take a look at this : http://cocos2d-x.org/programmersguide/12/

Comment: dinosaurSprite and dinosaurBody don't have function  setRestitution

Comment: dinosaurBody->getShape(0)->setRestitution(0.f); but nothing change

Comment: Try with: `    dinosaurBody->getShape(dinosaurBody->getTag())->setRestitution(0);
`

Comment: zero restitution not working for my case. bouncing forever